# How to revive an old 4.2.2 phone?

Tags: google-play-store, 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, google-play-services

Because of "reasons" (or at this point mostly out of curiosity) I find myself with an old Wiko Iggy phone running Android 4.2.2 that after being factory reset is unable to install anything at all from the play store. Searching for specific apps in the store returns only books or movies, searching for apps in a browser and opening the relative page on the store shows the app all right, but tapping "install" only goes so far as showing the permissions overview; agreeing and trying to install produces a "no connection" error (of course the phone is connected to a WiFi network and logged in into a google account).

Is there anything I can do? My suspicion is that I should somehow recover an old APK for play services and install that, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: I assume the "no connection" is caused by the problem that Android 4.2 has not TLS1.2 enabled by default for HTTPS connections. A large number of server now require that version or newer. Newer versions of Google Play Services and Play store may have implemented a workaround for this so installing them could be a solution. But you need to manually download both APKs for third party sites like apkmirror APKPure and so on.

Comment: Robert is correct, this is what I have to do on my old tablet because Google Play Store doesn't want to work for me... it's why I am trying to find a way to update my Android version with the low RAM flag